# Как зафиксировать определенные элементы массива на определенных индексах?

Tags: javascript

Есть условная корзина и список товаров по категориям: Булки - начинки - соусы. При нажатии на булку, в массив должна добавиться булка: первая - на верх, вторая - вниз. И если пользователь начинает выбирать другие элементы, они должны вставать между первой и второй булками.

Очень долго ломаю голову и не знаю куда двигаться.

Comment: Зачем и что фиксировать? Вы первый раз добавляете эл-ты, а второй и последующий добавляете их после первого/перед последним

Comment: Потому что такие условия задачи. Два элемента определенного типа должны быть фиксированными в списке

Comment: Вы не можете ничего "фиксировать", вы можете добавлять внутрь массива эл-ты

Comment: Да, я понимаю. Я это и имел ввиду.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Но это колхоз, написанный чисто для примера. Если это для реального проекта, лучше использовать другое решение, например `Object` вместо массива.

```js
let arr = [];

arr.splice(-1, 0, 'sausage'); // Добавляем сосиску

arr.unshift('first_bun'); // Добавляем первую булку в начало массива
arr.push('second_bun'); // ...и вторую в конец
// Выше две строки как раз приводят пример как вставить что-то в начало и в конец массива, если в нем уже что-то имелось.

arr.splice(-1, 0, 'sauce'); // Добавляем соус
arr.splice(-1, 0, 'onion'); // Добавляем лук

console.log('arr', arr); // Получаем нечто...[ 'first_bun', 'sausage', 'sauce', 'onion', 'second_bun' ]
```

Comment: Гигантское спасибо, это примерно то, что нужно!